# Delete space between the menu and the carousel Twitter bootstrap 2.2.2

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I just add navbar and then at the bottom of this add carousel like this in the screen: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/zrzutekranu2h.png/

In twitter bootstrap css I nothing changed. How I can delete this space?
this is my index.html code

```
    <!-- NavBar
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="assets/img/examples/slide-01.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/img/examples/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/img/examples/slide-03.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
    <div class="container">

      <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
      <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the navbar would fall over the content of the page because of `navbar-fixed-top`. You're actually setting a `padding-top` for the body to prevent this. That padding needs to be set to **`40px`**. It's probably set to more than that now.

**Again, this padding is set in your CSS or HTML, not in bootstrap itself.**

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I just change this:
   .carousel {
 top: -20px;
 width:100%;
 margin: 0px auto; 
    } And it works :D